# Android onClick custom PageAdapter

Tags: java, android, onclick, onclicklistener

So I have created a generic PageAdapter to be used in various parts on the app, which looks like this:

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private final Picasso picasso;
    private final int layoutResId;

    private final List<AssociatedMedia> images;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(Context context, int layoutResId) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        picasso = Injector.getInstance().getPicasso();
        this.layoutResId = layoutResId;
        this.images = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setMedia(List<AssociatedMedia> media) {
        images.clear();
        for (AssociatedMedia productMedia : media) {
            if (productMedia.type == AssociatedMediaType.IMAGE) {
                images.add(productMedia);
            }
            else {
                // non-images all at the end
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        AssociatedMedia image = images.get(position);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResId, container, false);
        container.addView(imageView);

        picasso.load(Uri.parse(image.urls[0])).into(imageView);

        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) object;
        container.removeView(imageView);

        picasso.cancelRequest(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

}
```

I then call this adapter in a fragment, like this:

```
ImagePagerAdapter productImageAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.photo_container_small);
            productImageAdapter.setMedia(medias);
            productImage.setAdapter(productImageAdapter);
```

My question is, how can I invoke a onClickListener in the fragment. So my scenario is that, we have a carousel of images, and once the user click on an image, it will open a large view on that image, so sort of need an onItemClickListener, but this can only be invoked in the pagerAdapter.

So is there a way to either call a onClickListener in the fragment, or notify the fragment from the adapter when an item has been clicked?

Comment: As the adapter "owns" its view, I would deal with the onClick within the adapter. For calling back on the fragment to inform about any paging events etc. I would introduce an interface, such as ImagePagerAdapterListener, that each fragment has to implement that makes use of the adapter. Initialize the adapter with  a reference to its listener and double check if the listener really implements this protcol. (e.g. catch a potential class cast exception when assigning the parameter of the constructor to the local variable)

Comment: BTW ImagePickerAdapter2 is not ImagePickerAdapter.

Comment: Yea yea, this was me just messing about with it. Great stuff. You wouldn't happen to have an example of this interface implementation anywhere?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. But it is just an interface in the end. BTW, in your case you don't need to do the exception catch trick. That was in my mind because of other framwork implications where we have to double check within the "sender" that the "receiver" of the data is of a certain type. I'll give it a try later.

Comment: So just to clarify, do I add the following interface:

public interface ImagePagerAdapterListener {
  void onClick(int position);
 }

in the fragment or the adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a response to your comment. For formating and size reasons I use an answer for it. It is a general example on how to use an interface to de-couple a fragment from an adapter class which makes the adapter re-usable in several fragments (and even other projects).

```
public class MyAdapter {

   MyAdapterListener listener;

   private MyAdapter() {}

   public MyAdapter(MyAdapterListener listeningActivityOrFragment) {

      listener = listeningActivityOrFragment;

   }
}



public interface MyAdapterListener {

   void somethingTheFragmentNeedsToKnow(Object someData);

}


public class SomeFragment extends Fragment implements  MyAdapterListener {

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // Inflate the layout for this fragment
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, container, false);

      // Do everyhting here to init your view.

      // Create an Adapter and bind it to this fragment
      MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);

      return view;

   }

// Implement the listener interface

   @Override
   public void somethingTheFragmentNeedsToKnow(Object someData) {

      // Get the data and process it.

   }
}
```

So in your case the method within the interface may well be `onClick(int position);` If you need more than one method, then just add them.